# PHP Fatal Error causing 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: magento2.3, aws, ubuntu

I recently started to work with a small merchant to set-up their first web-shop and chose Magento Community to do so.

While I have plenty of PHP, etc.. developer experience, Magento is new to me with a lot of set-up and configuration headaches along the way.

However I'm now getting a PHP Fatal Error logged as an Apache error as follows:

```
AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: ObjectManager isn't initialized in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager.php:36\nStack trace:\n#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/File/Transfer/Adapter/Http.php(47): Magento\\Framework\\App\\ObjectManager::getInstance()\n#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/pub/get.php(58): Magento\\Framework\\File\\Transfer\\Adapter\\Http->__construct(Object(Magento\\Framework\\HTTP\\PhpEnvironment\\Response), Object(Magento\\Framework\\File\\Mime))\n#2 {main}\n thrown in /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/ObjectManager.php on line 36', referer: https://www.our-domain-here.com/index.php
```

The issue is causing a 500 Internal Error in Chrome for images that I upload through the admin interface.
They also fail in the shop interface.
Images are stored in the DB, I can see them load into the DB fine and they exist in the directory the DB points to.
I can load the images fine with a direct URL reference but they fail in the shop and admin interfaces as the URL has a get.php call.

I'm thinking its permissions issues but have been through as much online help re this as I can find with no success so only info left to query is does the above error message help point to where Magento is falling over?

Thanks.